# Redirect this dynamic URL to html URL with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have lot or articles with this URL format:

```
mydomain/art/details.php?articleid=24463&parentid=1&catid=166
```

the above  is an example.

And i want that redirect these kind of URL to :

```
mydomain/art/24463.html
```

Please let me know that how can i do it with .htaccess?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Since `parentid` and `catid` are not in your new format url and are dynamic parameters, you can't have a generic rule. You must use `RewriteMap` or write a rule by url. Or you can add thoses params to your new format url and then it will be possible to write a generic rule

Comment: thanks,but i'm not familiar with rules in .htaccess ,please let me know how can i do it?

Comment: You could use a new format as `/art-166/1-24463.html` and then have a generic rule like `RewriteRule ^art-(\d+)/(\d)-(\d+)\.html$ /art/details.php?articleid=$3&parentid=$2&catid=$1 [L]`

Comment: What is your mean from 'new format'?

Comment: Well this is an example like yours: `mydomain/art/24463.html`. By `new format` i mean the new accessible url

Comment: Does it mean that for each article i must write a code in .htaccss?

Comment: You will have to only if you keep your new format. But if you chose mine (for instance) you won't. I already explained it in previous comments

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75844/discussion-between-kaveh-and-justin-iurman).

Comment: I used your code as  below but it doesn't redirect:                                                                      RewriteRule  ^art-(\d+)/(\d)-(\d+)\.html$ /art/details.php?articleid=$3&parentid=$2&catid=$1 [L]

Comment: Make sure to create your htaccess in root folder (and htaccess are allowed). Also, check if *mod_rewrite* is enabled. Then, don't forget to add `RewriteEngine On` before my rule. Finally, `http://domain.com/art-166/1-24463.html` should display the same content as `http://domain.com/art/details.php?articleid=24463&parentid=1&catid=166`

Comment: I have already the .heaccess file for another purpose and above the file (the first line is RewriteEngine On) but it doesn't redirect,what is the dash sign (-)after [L] ,i haven't put it

Comment: Sorry, i had confused regarding the dash sign,the  .htaccess is in root and my code is: RewriteRule ^art-(\d+)/(\d)-(\d+)\.html$  /art/details.php?articleid=$3&parentid=$2&catid=$1 [L]    but it doesn't redirect.

Comment: What url do you try with no luck ?

Comment: The url in example but and also another url like that but there is no redirect.

Comment: I checked the new url (http://domain.com/art-166/1-24463.html) and it works  good,thanks but my existing url are as example so how it is possible that i change the .htaccess so when user request the daynamic url then automatically redirect to .html url?

Comment: I've posted an answer explaining what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `mydomain/art/24463.html` you should choose something like `mydomain/art-166/1-24463.html`.

This way, you'll include also `parentid` and `catid` which are dynamic parameters (and so, needed for rewriting).

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/art/details\.php\?articleid=(\d+)&parentid=(\d+)&catid=(\d+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /art-%3/%2-%1.html? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^art-(\d+)/(\d+)-(\d+)\.html$ /art/details.php?articleid=$3&parentid=$2&catid=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks Justin,it works well and great,would you please let me know that the static format is prefer to daynamic specially from view of search engine?

Comment: Static is mainly better for users right now. You can find a note about it: http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2008/09/dynamic-urls-vs-static-urls.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this in [htaccess tester](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^art/(\d+).html$ art/details.php?articleid=$1&parentid=1&catid=166 [nc]
```

Comment: The problem here is that you have dynamic parameters such as `parentid` and `catid`. They can't be defined as static in your rule

Comment: thanks,but please not that  parenetid and catid change in different articles.